# Keyboard shortcut CAPSLOCK-SHIFT-TAB not working in Chrome on external keyboard after CAPSLOCK modified to CONTROL

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra

On my Macbook Pro with High Sierra 10.13.3, I have an Apple external keyboard. I used `System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys...` to make `CAPSLOCK` into another `CONTROL` key:

[image]

With this configuration, I can move one Chrome tab to the right with `CAPSLOCK-TAB`, very convenient.

**However, moving one tab to the left with `CAPSLOCK-SHIFT-TAB` doesn't work on the external keyboard.**

It *does* work on the laptop's built-in keyboard, oddly.

This is not Chrome's fault, because I see the same behavior in the Sublime Text app.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Apple's wireless keyboard, that will solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review